# Autofilling a pandas dataframe column after new incomplete row data is appended

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that consists of 3 columns, column 1 is Sympy symbols, column 2 is the value associated with them with arbitrary astropy units, column 3 is the value in SI astropy units. As I'm using the DataFrame in a notebook environment, I occasionally add new symbols (col 1) and values (col 2) via df.append, and view the new table as the analysis progresses. I would like the resulting output to auto fill col 3 based on col 2, instead of filling col 3 with N/A. I.E a similar workflow to using [excel tables](https://youtu.be/8cKzi45xAO8?t=485).

For simplicity's sake, we'll ignore the whole units thing. Here's what I effectively have.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[2,4],[5,2]],columns = ['A','B'])
df['Sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A']+x['B'], axis=1)
df['Product'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A']*x['B'], axis=1)
df = df.append({'A':9,'B':2}, ignore_index=True)
df
```

Here's the output:

```
     A    B  Sum  Product
0  1.0  3.0  4.0      3.0
1  2.0  4.0  6.0      8.0
2  5.0  2.0  7.0     10.0
3  9.0  2.0  NaN      NaN
```

Here's what I expected:

```
     A    B  Sum  Product
0  1.0  3.0  4.0      3.0
1  2.0  4.0  6.0      8.0
2  5.0  2.0  7.0     10.0
3  9.0  2.0  11.0    18.0
```

Is there a way to get the expected result without reapplying two lambda functions?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html,

Comment: Not sure how fillna() helps. None of the methods (e.g backfill, ffill etc.) do what I need.

Comment: Why not have Sum and Product while you append, in the dictionary itself? There is no auto fill mechanism in pandas, and even in excel. You have to copy the formula across new rows for it to work.

Comment: That's probably what I'll have to do. I was hoping not to have to do that.


As for the excel thing, that's not true. Make two columns and fill it with arbitrary data. Fill a third column based on the operation on the first 2 columns. Select all the data and hit ctrl+t. When you add data to a new row just below the lowest point in the table, the table expands, and the formula in the 3rd column automatically extends down, filling the previously empty 3rd column with data.

Comment: [Here's an example of it in excel](https://youtu.be/8cKzi45xAO8?t=485)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something that automatically computes your wanted values I don't think there's a simple way to do this.
The simplest thing you can do is to reapply the functions every time you add a new row.

Alternatively you can write `df.transform(lambda x: """operation you need""")` butit's basically what you're trying to avoid.